# Arguments for having a simple POCO for models

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am a programmer, and I think I'm well educated in OO. I believe in a POCO (C#) and a model that only has get/set methods to encapsulate data. 3 layer domain models.

I'm looking for documentation that support value for having a simple domain model and all business logic in the service layer and a DAL for data access.

Martin Fowler:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

is saying that a (anaemic) domain model has no value, and for it to have value it must handle the buslogic or/and data CRUD operation.
I need some good books that has some counterarguments for Martin Fowler.
(this is not a case of dismissing Martin Fowler, I respect the work. I'm looking for a better understanding of what we are doing and why? )

Comment: Here're some counter-arguments from a Java world: [Adam Bien: Should JPA entities contain business logic?](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/should_jpa_entities_contain_business)

Answer (score 2):

You can find counterarguments from... Fowler himself.

[PoEAA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420), p. 110, *Transaction script* :

> However much of an object bigot you become, don't rule out Transaction
>   Script. There are a lot of simple problems out there, and a simple
>   solution will get you up and running much faster.

A Transaction Script is not exactly the kind of service you describe (it might not use domain objects, even anemic ones), but it's pretty close.

Also, note that the notion of POCO doesn't assume anything about the dumbness or anemic-ness of an object. You can have rich domain POCOs with behavior in them. POCO/POJO describes a simple native object, as opposed to an object decorated with annotations or attributes, or that inherits a special class from a framework, often for persistence purposes.

Comment: _POCO/POJO describes a simple native object, as opposed to an object decorated with annotations or attributes_. Does that mean that JPA `@Entity`ies are not POJOs?

Comment: Old story, still has value. If the OP is asking counter-arguments to Fowler's diktat, I think that quoting Fowler doesn't answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [DCI architecture](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html), it separates data from behavior in an attempt to control software evolution by splitting parts that incur different rates of change from each other. It also uses the notion of a role, or trait, to achieve the desired functionality of putting the data and the behavior back together.

There's a book that tackles the broader subject of architecture emphasizing DCI: *Lean Architecture for Agile Software Development* by James Coplien.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Fowler, [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html):

> In essence the problem
>   with anemic domain models is that they incur all of the costs of a
>   domain model, without yielding any of the benefits.

Costs include mapping your objects to a database and the effort you put into designing your (anemic) domain model. If you've decided you don't need the benefits of DDD and the anemic-model-associated costs are acceptable you've got yourself a counter argument.

However, make sure your anemic model + services + DAL (+UI?) is cheaper than an [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) application (Ruby on Rails? Grails?) with some [transaction scripts](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html).

Domain driven design is typically applied when we want to *simplify* a complex problem, not to "complexify" a simple one. Again quoting [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html):

> Domain Models aren't always the best tool.

Analyze your requirements, pick a suitable architecture and deliver your application.

Comment: So what is the best way of dealing with a large scale application (huge system) witch need to handle WWW and maybe also client-server desktop calls.
Is it using ActiveRecord or POCO ?

Comment: That's really hard to answer without knowing more context. The "scale" of the system isn't the most important factor when considering DDD over `ActiveRecord`. Choosing `ActiveRecord` does not imply a "small-scale" system. Take Github for instance (pretty large scale); if I'm not mistaken, they use Ruby on Rails for front end. Twitter also has used Ruby on Rails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761826/what-language-i-e-php-ruby-on-rails-does-twitter-use. Time to Market is valuable too.